# Join multiple lines based on pattern

Tags: regular-expression, global-command, join

I have text bounded by quotes as follows

```
"This is
an example
of some text"
```

I want to join these into one line. e.g.

```
"This is an example of some text"
```

I have tried commands like the following:

```
:g/^"\_[^"]\+"$/j
```

However, while this matches the text I'm looking for, it appears to only join on the first line.

I think this is due to `:g` only working with the first line of the match. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I found something on the [Vim wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Ranges#Ranges_with_marks_and_searches) that combines ranges with searches.

This command did the trick for me:

```
:g/^"/,/"$/j
```

e.g.

```
:g         (global)
/^"/,/"$/  (a range between a line starting with " and a line ending with ")
j          (join the lines specified in the range)
```

Comment: Note that we assume that every time we have a quote at the start of a line, it is followed by a quote at the end of another line. This was true for me, but may not be true for you!